# GGtext following group_split and map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to use `ggtext` when creating plots with `group_split` and `map`(~ggplot...).? How can I pass on the value rather than the name. Below a reprex. Many thanks!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(patchwork)


list_plot <- mtcars %>% 
  group_split(gear) %>% 
  map(~ggplot(.)+
        labs(title=paste("Number of gears:", 
                         unique(.x$gear)))+
        geom_bar(aes(x=carb),
                 stat="count")+
        theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
  )

patchwork::wrap_plots(list_plot)+
  plot_layout(ncol=1)
```

[image]

```r
list_plot <- mtcars %>% 
  group_split(gear) %>% 
  map(~ggplot(.)+
        labs(title=paste("Number of gears: <span style='color:orange'> unique(.x$gear) </span>"))+
        geom_bar(aes(x=carb),
                 stat="count")+
        theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
  )


patchwork::wrap_plots(list_plot)+
  plot_layout(ncol=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Have you tried putting ` unique(.x$gear) ` outside the quote-marks?

Comment: @teunbrand yes.
list_plot <- mtcars %>% 
   group_split(gear) %>% 
   map(~ggplot(.)+
         labs(title=paste0("Number of gears:", <span style='color:orange'> unique(.x$gear)</span>))+
Error: unexpected '<' in:"  map(~ggplot(.)+
        labs(title=paste0("Number of gears:", <"
>         geom_bar(aes(x=carb),
+                  stat="count")+
+         theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?
>   )
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"

Comment: `paste("Number of gears: <span style='color:orange'>", unique(.x$gear), "</span>")` ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very specific. I meant the following: `labs(title=paste("Number of gears: <span style='color:orange'>", unique(.x$gear), "</span>"))`

Comment: many thx. didn't know that I can 'break-up' the span expression.

Comment: That's the point of using `paste`. I don't think you don't need `paste` otherwise.